# How to remove ith column of a matrix using for loop

Tags: matlab, matrix

Using MatLab, I am attempting to begin with a matrix,

| column1 | column2 | column3 | column4 | column5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 7 | 10 | 11 |
| 2 | 5 | 8 | 11 | 12 |
| 3 | 6 | 9 | 12 | 13 |

and use a for loop to obtain 5 matrices, one with each of the columns removed, according to:

| column2 | column3 | column4 | column5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 7 | 10 | 11 |
| 5 | 8 | 11 | 12 |
| 6 | 9 | 12 | 13 |

| column1 | column3 | column4 | column5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 7 | 10 | 11 |
| 2 | 8 | 11 | 12 |
| 3 | 9 | 12 | 13 |

| column1 | column2 | column4 | column5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 10 | 11 |
| 2 | 5 | 11 | 12 |
| 3 | 6 | 12 | 13 |

| column1 | column2 | column3 | column5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 7 | 11 |
| 2 | 5 | 8 | 12 |
| 3 | 6 | 9 | 13 |

| column1 | column2 | column3 | column4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 7 | 10 |
| 2 | 5 | 8 | 11 |
| 3 | 6 | 9 | 12 |

Please note that it is extremely important that this be done IN A LOOP, so as to be replicable for an arbitrary number of columns, as I have managed to code this for a known number of columns already.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

That's a pretty straightforward problem for Matlab or Octave. I wonder what your problem was?

```
m = [
  1 4 7 10 11
  2 5 8 11 12
  3 6 9 12 13
];

outmatrices = {};

for col = 1:size(m,2)
  outmatrices{end+1} = [m(:,1:col-1), m(:,col+1:end)];
end

outmatrices
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use arrayfun( ) for this, which will handle any matrix size and hide the looping behind the function call. E.g.,

```
result = arrayfun(@(k)[m(:,1:k-1),m(:,k+1:end)],1:size(m,2),'uni',false);
```

The result will be a cell array with the various matrices as the cell elements.